# Can't access FreeNAS Jail via router VPN

Tags: networking, ssh, router, freebsd, truenas

I have a VPN running on my Linksys router. I have been able to configure a client to connect to it, and can access my FreeNAS server via the web interface with no issues. I can also ping it. But, I can not access the Jails that are running on it.

I have a Jail with SSH enabled, and when I am on the local network, I can access the Jail via port 22 with no issues. When I then connect externally via the VPN, I can not connect via SSH, nor will the Jail respond to a ping.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue where I can't access jails from a different subnet on my local network. I'm guessing it's a routing issue on the FreeNAS box, but I haven't figured it out yet.